# How to sum up all the contingency tables into one? in R

Tags: r, sum, contingency

I have many contingency tables (100) in many sheets gathered in one excel file. Some of them have more attributes than the other. But at the end they all have the same columns and rows name. (either more attributes or less).
For example let's say we have these 2 tables.

[image]

[image]

I want to add each cell that belong to the same class (row - Person1 type B and column B_1 cell in the first table will add up with row - Person1 type B and column B_1 cell in the second table and so on)

The final table will be like this. Notice D was not there in the first table so it is going to be there as it is.

[image]

I want to sum up (pool) all the contingency tables into one with all the available attributes. How to achieve this in R?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your expected output.  And provide your input data via `dput()` rather than as an image.

Comment: agree with @Limey. Also, a sample excel-file would help a lot in answering...

Comment: @Limey I've added more explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @Wimpel I got this from the excel file. I put it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a excel-file, i cooked up a file based on your images provided..

It looks like this
[image]
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyxl)
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(unpivotr)

file_to_read <- "./testdata.xlsx"
# Get all names of sheets in the file
sheet_names <- readxl::excel_sheets(file_to_read)
# Loop through sheets
L <- lapply(sheet_names, function(x) {
  all_cells <-
    tidyxl::xlsx_cells(file_to_read, sheets = x) %>%
    dplyr::select(sheet, row, col, data_type, character, numeric)
  # Cells with the actual data  
  cells_data <-
    dplyr::filter(all_cells, row >= 3, col >= 3) %>%
    dplyr::transmute(row, col, sheet = sheet, value = numeric)
  # Select the headers
  person.number.up <-
    dplyr::filter(all_cells, row == 1) %>%
    dplyr::select(row, col, person.number.up = character)
  person.type.up <- 
    dplyr::filter(all_cells, row == 2) %>%
    dplyr::select(row, col, person.type.up = character)
  person.number.left <-
    dplyr::filter(all_cells, col == 1) %>%
    dplyr::select(row, col, person.number.left = character)
  person.type.left <- 
    dplyr::filter(all_cells, col == 2) %>%
    dplyr::select(row, col, person.type.left = character)
  #put together
  final.df <- cells_data %>%
    unpivotr::enhead(person.number.up, "up-ish") %>%
    unpivotr::enhead(person.type.up, "up-ish") %>%
    unpivotr::enhead(person.number.left, "left-ish") %>%
    unpivotr::enhead(person.type.left, "left-ish") %>%
    dplyr::select(-(1:2))
})
# Put together in a data.table
DT <- data.table::rbindlist(L, use.names = TRUE)
# Cast to wide, summing values in the process
ans <- dcast(DT, person.number.left + person.type.left ~ person.number.up + person.type.up, 
      value.var = "value", 
      fun.aggregate = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: note: you might need `unpivotr::justify()` to set the headers to the upper left corners of your data to avoid ties... see `unpivotr::direction()` under the `-ish`-section

Comment: What is this line for?   # Cells with the actual data  
  cells_data <-
    dplyr::filter(all_cells, row >= 3, col >= 3) %>%
    dplyr::transmute(row, col, sheet = sheet, value = numeric)

Comment: Thanks for the preprocessing step. I added the headers manually for each table to refer to a specific person (just like what you did but manually to get more accurate results. I have like five types and each table is different). Then, I changed the numbers in this section (# Select the headers) to the names in that column instead. for example (person.number.up <-
    dplyr::filter(all_cells, row == "person1") %>%
    dplyr::select(row, col, person.number.up = character)). I got this error, (Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `row` doesn't exist)

Comment: I updated the question with the data I have.

Comment: now you are asking a completely different question. better to start a new one. And make it reproducible (see FAQ). You will not get the best/fastest answers if you only post images of data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated the question here and it would be very appreciated if you help me out with this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692461/sum-up-tables-results-from-multiple-sheets-into-one-table-in-r/67692975?noredirect=1#comment119651896_67692975